# iPhone Programming: Applying Alpha to Parent but not to Child Views

Tags: iphone, uiview, alpha

Is it possible to set Alpha to .75 or .50 (transparent) for Parent view but the Child views/controls are opaque (Alpha channel 1.0 - completely visible).

Whenever i set Alpha of my main UIView to transparent, all the child views/controls are also shown as transparent. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The parent that acts as your background should be changed to a sibling before the container that wraps your children. That way you can set the transparency without affecting the entire hierarchy.

This would look like this.

- `<item-container>`

  - `<item-background>`
  - `<children-container>`

    - `<children/>`

This hierarchy, would have the same visibility order and let you set the opacity independently of the contents of the children container.

Answer (score 79):

One simpler way is also possible without making the views siblings. Don't set the alpha directly on the parent view. Instead use

```
[parentView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
```

Now any child view can have its own color and will NOT be transparent.

In Swift, this would be

```
parentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7)
```

Comment: Worked a treat; exactly what I needed. Thank you!!

Comment: It doesn't work for me on iOS 11? Background is black without transparent.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a late answer, and something has already been accepted, but I found the best solution for me is not to set the `UIView`'s transparency directly, but instead set it's background color to 0,0,0,0, making the color fully transparent.

Comment: Just to be clear (pun fully intended), you do this using the following code on the parents view: [myUIView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but if you'd like to have a container view with a transparent background you can do so by setting the backgroundColor property to [UIColor clearColor]. That way you can see through the background, but all of the subviews will remain opaque. If you'd like the background to be semi-transparent just use [UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:].

If you want the entire view to be semi-transparent while other views are not you'll have to make them siblings.